# SOQL to dynamically identify all its child object

Tags: soql

Payment1 and Payment2 has a lookup relationship with Case. Now I need to write a SOQL to get call its child object dynamically. Case could  have record for Payment1 or Payment-2 or both Payment-1 and Payment-2.

```
List<Case> caseList = [Select Id,OwnerId, (select Id, OwnerId, CreatedById from Payment__r), 
                                        (select Id,OwnerId,CreatedById from Payment_2__r) 
                                         FROM Case 
                                         WHERE Id IN :newCasesMap.keySet()];
```

How to identify the Payment-1 only present or Payment-2 only present or both Payment1 and Payment-2 present ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the query you already have, the code could look like this:

```
for (Case c : caseList) {
    Boolean p1 = c.Payment__r.size() > 0;
    Boolean p2 = c.Payment_2__r.size() > 0;
    if (p1 && p2) {
        // Add code for both present
    } else if (p1) {
        // Add code for p1 only present
    } else if (p2) {
        // Add code for p2 only present
    } else {
        // Add code for neither present
    }
}
```

Note that the relationship name from parent to child normally defaults to a plural; if that is the case here the names would be `Payments__r` and `Payment_2s__r`.

If you don't need the payment records and just want to count them, you could use an [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) instead.

Comment: Hey thanks ! I want to also get the Payment__r and  Payment_2__r records and create share object for them..

Comment: @Kanika Your query already has those records in the lists, just iterate over them and create the share records.

Comment: Sometime for ex: Payment_2__r doesnot have any records to its breaking here Boolean p2 = c.Payment_2__r.size() > 0;

Comment: @Kanika If there are no records an empty list is returned so that test should still work. Exactly what error are you seeing?